# OS X failed system update

Tags: software-update, auto-update

I'm on OS X 10.10.4, MacBook Pro retina and it alerts me that my 10.10.5 update is ready to install. However, I'm on a very slow internet up to now and according to my router log I did not download more than 100MB data. And sure enough, the /Library/updates/ folder contains OSXUpd10.10.5Patch.pkg and FirmwareUpdate.pkg, which when opened with an unarchiver(betterzip and 7 zip) told me the files are corrupted. Can I just delete the files for a re-download or shall I do something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Apple's Downloads Page](http://support.apple.com/downloads) and re-download it manually.

Comment: And put it into the library/updates folder or just double click them? What about the accompanying FirmwareUpdate? Thanks!

Comment: @egwenesedai nope, just open the .pkg and install